# Modprobe error while installing Docker on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, linode

I've just installed Docker on Ubuntu 14.04 (linode) but while it's being installed I saw this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open 
          moddep file '/lib/modules/4.1.0-x86_64-linode59/modules.dep.bin'
Warning: current kernel is not supported by the linux-image-extra-virtual package.  
         We have no AUFS support.  Consider installing the packages
         linux-image-virtual kernel and linux-image-extra-virtual for AUFS support.
```

After installing, it seems that Docker works.. `sudo docker images` and `sudo docker ps` are done without any errors. Should I worry on this error message? Should I install suggested packages (`linux-image-virtual` and `linux-image-extra-virtual`)?

Comment: Run `docker info` to see what storage driver it's using. If you're happy with what it's using, I guess it's not a problem.

Comment: @AdrianMouat, `docker info` says that I have this storage driver `Storage Driver: devicemapper`. My containers use volumes for any data that changes, so I think I really don't need aufs.. Am I right?

Comment: If you're happy with devicemapper, that's fine. The container file system is more about sharing base images rather than data. There are a lot of questions on SO regarding devicemapper, so if it causes you problems you might want to look into changing.

Comment: BTW, I've just tested it on Digital Ocean, there isn't the error like above and `docker info` says that `Storage Driver: aufs` :)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I added an answer for the sake of closing this. But remember this is to with the _container_ file system, not volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several storage drivers in Docker, which are ranked in order of preference. The error message is telling you that Docker tried to the AUFS driver, but failed and fell back to the devicemapper driver.

Unless you have problems with devicemapper, I wouldn't worry about it.

You can find more info on the various drivers in this presentation: https://jpetazzo.github.io/assets/2015-03-03-not-so-deep-dive-into-docker-storage-drivers.html